# Does there exist a uniformly continuous surjection $f: \Bbb Q^c\to \Bbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Does there exist a uniformly continuous surjection $f:\Bbb Q^c\to\Bbb Q$?

This question arose to my mind after constructing a continuous surjection from $\Bbb Q^c$ to $\Bbb Q$. Which is a very simple construction, that is $f(x)=\Big\lceil\frac{1}{x}\Big\rceil$ gives a continuous surjection from $\Bbb Q^c\to\Bbb N$, now taking an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, say $\{q_n\}$ we construct a map $h:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$ as $h(n)=q_n$ (clearly continuous and surjective), now $(h\circ f):\Bbb Q^c\to\Bbb Q$ is the required continuous surjection from $\Bbb Q^c$ to $\Bbb Q$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't $g(I_n)$ be a singleton? if you have one $g$ that works, you can make room for arbitrarily long constant sections in it with losing either surjectivity or uniform continuity.

Comment: @Troposphere I said not all $g(I_n)$ can singleton

Comment: @Troposphere Yes

Comment: That might be what you meant, but what you _said_ was "for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $g(I_n)$ can't be a singleton".

Comment: @Troposphere Ok, I am editing that one

Comment: @Troposphere Is it fine now?

Comment: As far as I can see you're still saying, "for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $g(I_n)$ can't be a singleton". That's still a claim that you say each $n$ will satisfy _separately_.

Comment: Apart from that phrasing the proof looks valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, such $f$ exists. Now, since $\Bbb Q^c$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ and $f$ is a uniformly continuous function, so it can be extended continuously on $\Bbb R$. Let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be such extension.

Now consider the restriction of $g$ on $I_n=[n,n+1]\,\,\forall\,\,n\in\Bbb N$ is continuous. Hence $g(I_n)$ is compact and connected.

Now consider, $g(I_{n_0})=[a,b]$ for some $a\neq b$ for some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ 
(Note that, there exists such $I_{n_0}$, since not for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $g(I_n)$ can be a singleton.)
Now, $g(I_{n_0})=g(I_{n_0}\,\cap\,\Bbb Q^c)\,\cup\,g(I_{n_0}\,\cap\,\Bbb Q)$ is countable, since $g(I_{n_0}\,\cap\,\Bbb Q^c)\subset\Bbb Q$ and $g(I_{n_0}\,\cap\,\Bbb Q)$ is atmost coutable but $[a,b]$ is uncountable. (Which is a contradiction.)